# Browser settings to block css and images

Tags: windows, browser

I'm looking for a way to browse the web without the distraction of colours and images. Most of the time, I like colours and images in web sites but there are occasions when I just want to get to the information without all the glare.

Have any of you found a browser or browser-configuration that you use to display text only?

Notes:

- Kind of like Lynx but not a console application.
- Must work on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The [Readability bookmarklet](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/) may be just what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 That looked very promising. Although, it seems to strip out a lot of text as well...

Comment: It is a bit hit or miss.  I think it's designed mainly for sites where you're reading an article, and there's a lot of superfluous stuff in sidebars, etc.  In those cases, it works great.

Answer (score 2):

For those with [Opera](http://www.opera.com/):

```
View -> Images -> No Images
View -> Styles -> User Mode (to disable CSS) or 
                  one of the various presets (e.g., High Contrast)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With **Firefox** you can reduce a lot of stuff using just two addons, and still retain most of the browsing experience:

[**Adblock Plus**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865)

[image]

[**NoScript**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722)

[image]

These addons allow you to selectively activate full access quickly, and block a lot of images and embedded content that you wish to skip.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, you can apply [your own CSS styles](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#userContent) to all websites using the userContent.css file in the chrome folder in [your profile folder](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles).

You could add the rule:

```
* {background-color: white !important; color: black !important;}
```

Which would make everything apart from images (and maybe a few other things like borders, which could always be added to the rule) black on white. Then you could turn images off in the Content section of Firefox's Options/Preferences.

You could also Google [CSS Reset](http://www.google.com/#q=CSS+Reset) for inspiration for more rules (you'll need to add !important to any rules as above to override the site's CSS).

Answer (score 0):

[Web Developer 1.1.8](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/60) for firefox

Comment: To elaborate on martani_net's answer, you can use Web Developer to disable CSS entirely or change to your own definitions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the web developer toolbar on firefox to do it page by page, but i think you want to do it for all pages, so it might not be the best option.